# Java - Gson parse "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT"

Tags: java, gson

I have a JSON similar to this which I get it by sending HTTP request.

```
{
      "0": {
        "name": "Chunk",
        "type": "magic",
        "item": "Chestplate",
        "item_min_lvl": "70",
        "id": {
          "health": "0.3",
          "spell": "24%",
          "life": "0.1",
          "xp": "24%",
          "loot": "22%"
        },
        "def": "67"
      },
      "1": {
        "name": "Thor",
        "type": "normal",
        "item": "Shoe",
        "item_min_lvl": "12",
        "id": {
          "xp": "24%"
        },
        "def": "12"
      },
      "2": {
        "name": "Clipper",
        "type": "normal",
        "item": "Sword",
        "item_min_lvl": "51",
        "id": {
          "health": "1",
          "life": "0.12",
          "xp": "4%"
        },
        "min_dam": "11",
        "max_dam": "7"
      }

}
```

Here is my code:

```
java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> list = gson.fromJson(json, type);//Error here
for(Map<String, Object> m : list)
{
    //blah
}
```

It returns this error `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2`

Can anyone help me to solve this error? I am new to `JSON` and `GSON`. Please note, some of the  the "items" aren't the same so I have to use `TypeToken`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You json does not include arrays (with syntax `[]`) but objects (with syntax `{}`).

You probably need to use `new TypeToken<Map<String, <Map<String, Object>>>>(){}.getType();`

Comment: do I need to modify `for(Map<String, Object> m : list)` ?

Comment: yes, but rather using `for(Map<String, Object> m : list.values())` as list will be a `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>`

Comment: Uhh same error at this `       ArrayList<Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> list = gson.fromJson(json, type);`

Comment: There is no array. java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, <Map<String, Object>>>>(){}.getType();Map<String, <Map<String, Object>>> map = gson.fromJson(json, type); for(Map<String, Object> m : map.values()) { /****/ } Also, Im not sure you need to specify the while type hierarchy using gson. Use JSonObject obj = gson.fromJson();

Comment: If your json might differ, consider using JsonObject and adding checks to see if the property you want to read is actually a jsonobject. In other word, go down the object hierarchy manually.